# MS SQL Server organization and memory

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a MS SQL server that I've start working with and I think I have an idea on the organization of MS SQL Server but I'm not absolutely sure of that idea's correctness. In relation to this idea, I have a question about a memory setting that might be an issue if my assumptions are correct. 
My assumptions:

1. I know you can have multiple SQL servers on a Host server and that they are connected to by SSMS as separate connections.
2. You can have multiple Databases under the given server.

The host server has 24GB of RAM. From what I can tell, there is only one MS SQL server running. Under this SQL Server there are several databases.

While digging around in the settings I found a setting that set the "Maximum server memory (in MB)" to 8192MB.

Based on my assumptions that the databases are not separate "servers", would
 it be correct to say that all of those databases are sharing the 8192MB of RAM?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/server-memory-server-configuration-options

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Based on my assumptions that the databases are not separate "servers", would it be correct to say that all of those databases are sharing the 8192MB of RAM?

That's Right..

You are assigning memory to an  instance of sqlserver(multiple instances can coexist in same box) and databases share memory available to them

Comment: Thank you very much. This is definitely something that I will have to address.

Comment: Glad it helped,check out this to know more on which book/links are helpfull for beginners:https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/13851/where-to-start-learning-to-understand-sql-server-architecture-and-internals